# Validate Consumer Group is created on topic or not

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am working on project where I need to validate consumer group is created on topic or not. Is there any way in **bold**Spring Kafka**bold** to validate it

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I haven't seen `describeConsumerGroups` supported in `Spring-Kafka` **KafkaAdmin**. So, you may need to create a `Kafka` **AdminClient** and call the method by yourself.

E.g: Here, I took advantage of the auto-configuration property class `KafkaProperties` and autowired it to the service.

```java
@Service
public class KafkaBrokerService implements BrokerService {
    private Map<String, Object> configs;
    
    public KafkaBrokerService(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) { // Autowired
        this.configs = kafkaProperties.buildAdminProperties();
    }

    private AdminClient createAdmin() {
        Map<String, Object> configs2 = new HashMap<>(this.configs);
        return AdminClient.create(configs2);
    }

    public SomeDto consumerGroupDescription(String groupId) {
        try (AdminClient adminClient = createAdmin()) {
            // ConsumerGroup's members
            ConsumerGroupDescription consumerGroupDescription = adminClient.describeConsumerGroups(Collections.singletonList(groupId))
                    .describedGroups().get(groupId).get();

            // ConsumerGroup's partitions and the committed offset in each partition
            Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsets = adminClient.listConsumerGroupOffsets(groupId).partitionsToOffsetAndMetadata().get();

            // When you get the information, you can validate it here.
            ...
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            // 
        }
    }
}
```